# ¿Cómo aumentar y disminuir el valor que hay en textview a traves de dos image view uno de sumar y otra de restar usando java en Android studio?

Tags: java, android

image view sumar image view restar image view valor

```
introducir el código aquí
```

¿Cómo aumentar y disminuir el valor que hay en textview a traves de dos image view uno de sumar y otra de restar usando java en Android studio?

```
      //inicializo Suma de Monedas

    sumarm10=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView40);
    sumarm10.setOnClickListener(this);

   
    //inicializo Resta de Monedas
    restarm10=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView41);
    restarm10.setOnClickListener(this);
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView55: //toca Atras
            startActivity(new Intent(this, IngresarDinero1.class));

            break;
        case R.id.imageView56:  //toca PulgarArriba
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ValidarMonedas.class));
            break;
        case R.id.imageView40://SUMAR 10

            break;
       
        case R.id.imageView41://RESTAR 10

            break;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, podrías crear una variable n tipo int e ir aumentando en 10 al pulsar en la imagen o reduciendo según convenga. Luego con hacer un setText(String.valueOf(n)) al textView seria suficiente.

En codigo:

```
//Te falta inicializar el textview
Textview texto =  findViewById(R.id.textView);

//En los case correspondientes


case R.id.imageView40://SUMAR 10
n+=10;
texto.setText(String.valueOf(n));
break;
case R.id.imageView41://RESTAR 10
n+=-10;
texto.setText(String.valueOf(n));
break;
```

Comment: Gracias es similar al código que funciona. Me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor en este caso es usar un `EditText` en lugar de `TextView` para que puedas editar tu valor.

Suponiendo que tu `EditText`  es `myTextView` y siempre tiene un valor númerico puedes realizar lo siguiente, convirtiendo el valor del `TextView` a entero (usando `Integer.parse(...)`), aumentarlo o disminuirlo en 10 y posteriormente agregando el valor a tu TextView (`myTextView.setText(String.vallueOf(valor))`) :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView55: //toca Atras
            startActivity(new Intent(this, IngresarDinero1.class));

            break;
        case R.id.imageView56:  //toca PulgarArriba
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ValidarMonedas.class));
            break;
        case R.id.imageView40://SUMAR 10

            int valor = Integer.parse(myTextView.getText().toString()); //Obtiene valor y lo convierte a entero.
            valor = valor +10;  //resta
            myTextView.setText(String.vallueOf(valor)); //Define nuevamente valor en TextView

            break;           
        case R.id.imageView41://RESTAR 10

            int valor = Integer.parse(myTextView.getText().toString()); //Obtiene valor y lo convierte a entero.
            valor = valor - 10;  //resta
            myTextView.setText(String.vallueOf(valor)); //Define nuevamente valor en TextView

            break;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Bueno resolvi la duda y ya está funcionando. Gracias por su ayuda